# 99 grand jeep cherokee limited v8 4 wheel drive

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee

I have a 99 grand jeep cherokee limited 183,190 miles. Around Christmas my kids and i were coming back from the mall. While exiting off of the highway it all of a sudden started acting as if it didn't have any gas. It completely cut off on us on the ramp. Tried to crank the car back up, and even though it did crank it wouldn't accelerate. I floored the gas and still the same thing. So i have to leave it. The next day i came back to get it and it started fine and ran awesome... for about a mile, then started doing the same thing. So i had it towed to my grandmother's to see of my grandfather could fix it. He has had it for about 4 months now. He said my fuel filter is fine got a new battery, new belt, i have transmission fluid, gas, oil. Now two days ago my grandfather calls me and says he put the battery in and he drove it around the neighborhood and it ran fine he said all i needed was some more gas when i pick it up. I picked it up today. It started fine and ran great all the way home, i live about 6 miles from them. Got it home turned it off, i was in the house for about 45 min. When i came back out to take it to be cleaned it started fine but when i put it in reverse i didn't even get 5 ft it cut off. I started it back up and again it started acting like it wasn't getting any gas. What could be my issue. Im a woman so i have no clue and this is my kids and i only means of transportation. HELP PLEASE!

Comment: Sounds like fuel pump has low pressure, with fuel going to vapor lock after things get hot.  With that said... what exactly is the your estimation of the life of this vehicle?  My guess is it should last exactly 175,000 miles before a major engine rebuild is required, or you drop it off at the scrap yard.  If you have no rust, no accident, a rebuild is probably worth the $$.

Comment: So since it's past 175,000 miles it may be a engine problem?

Comment: No. Engines get worn (low compression) leak oil (worn bushings and seals). This problem sounds like either fuel system or electrical ignition. My point is is it worth spending a few hundred $$ on a vehicle that might not last another 10,000 miles?  This problem can be fixed until the next problem arrives. An engine rebuild cost $3000 or more but gets you a whole lot more vehicle life.  Where are you going?  Are your expectations realistic??